# React Native : Native method ExpoLocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync expects 0 arguments but received 1

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm in need of your expertise in React Native.

I'm trying to use `expo-local-authentication` for local fingerprint authentication for my application.
My project was created using `expo init` command.

I have done the setup as per the documentation and still running into a strange issue:
Below is the error I'm facing for `LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync(options)`:

> Native method ExpoLocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync expects 0
> arguments but received 1

Here is the required part of my code:

```js
import * as LocalAuthentication from 'expo-local-authentication';

const authenticate = async () => {
    const hasHardwareAsync = await LocalAuthentication.hasHardwareAsync();

    if (hasHardwareAsync) {
      const supportedAuthentications = await LocalAuthentication.supportedAuthenticationTypesAsync();

      if (supportedAuthentications.indexOf(1) !== -1) {
        // Finger print supported
        const isFingerprintEnrolled = await LocalAuthentication.isEnrolledAsync();

        if (isFingerprintEnrolled) {
          const options = {
            promptMessage: 'Authenticate yourself',
          };
          try {
            // Also tried with await but it throws the same error 
            // await LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync(options)
            
            LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync(options).then(result => {
              // I never get inside this block
              console.warn(result)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.warn('Authentication Error: ', error)
            })
          } catch (error) {
            console.warn(error)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Not sure what I'm missing. Seems like there is no information available about the error. I also tried to run the `LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync()` without any arguments but it still throws the same error.

Any help on what could be the root cause of the issue and how can I resolve it or any other alternative for local authentication would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Im only getting this issue when I try to use devices with Facial biometrics on android

Comment: Yes Sameer, I figured it out. It was my mistake only. I used "yarn add expo-local-authentication" instead of "expo install expo-local-authentication". After using "expo install expo-local-authentication", my problems were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Update your app to the latest version of `expo` (38 in my case) and to the latest version of `expo-local-authentication`, and the error goes away.